# EF6 code-first insert foreign key constraint fail

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've run into a weird bug working with EF6 when inserting a record in the database.

I've some records in a table Invoices and later I want to add some records in a table `Lsvs`.

My object Lsv must have an Invoice but an Invoice does not necessarily have a `Lsv`.

Here is the code I wrote (only part of the classes):

```
public class Lsv
{
    public Guid InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public virtual Lsv Lsv { get; set; }
}
```

And when creating a Lsv:

```
var invoice = Domain.Query<Invoice>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == invoiceId);

if (invoice == null)
{
    throw new EntityNotFoundException();
}

// Create the Lsv
var lsv = new Lsv
{
    Amount = invoice.TotalDue.Incl,
    BvrReference = invoice.BankIdentifier,
    InvoiceDueDate = invoice.DueDate,
    DebitorOrganizationNodeId = invoice.DebitorOrganizationNodeId,
    InvoiceId = invoice.Id,
    ContactId = invoice.ContactId,
    OrganizationNodeId = invoice.OrganizationNodeId
};
```

I'm 100% sure the invoice exists in the database (when debugging, I'm getting the Id to query the DB I find the invoice).

Then when submitting changes I get an exception

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Lsvs_dbo.Invoices_Id". The conflict occurred in database "Echino-Dev_StephM", table "dbo.Invoices", column 'Id'.

But If I do

```
var lsv = new Lsv
            {
                Amount = invoice.TotalDue.Incl,
                BvrReference = invoice.BankIdentifier,
                InvoiceDueDate = invoice.DueDate,
                DebitorOrganizationNodeId = invoice.DebitorOrganizationNodeId,
                InvoiceId = invoice.Id,
                Invoice = invoice,
                ContactId = invoice.ContactId,
                OrganizationNodeId = invoice.OrganizationNodeId
            };
```

Notice that I set the InvoiceId and the Invoice - then it works and I can insert my data into the database.

Does anyone have any idea why setting only the `InvoiceId` field throws an error when inserting the `Lsv` object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the InvoiceId = invoice.Id.
The reason is, that in the database the references are the keys, but in C# the references are the objects itself. So if you set the child.ParentId = Parent.Id, is not enough (and not needed at all), but setting the child.Parent = Parent will work fine.

Comment: That was one of the things I try but doing so I got empty Guid in the database for the field InvoiceId

Comment: @S.Martignier you need to configure the Id fields as `Identity` columns in order to avoid EF inserting `Guid.Empty` for you.

Comment: Are you talking about the Id field in the Invoice? Because it's marked as Identity
`TableColumn(ColumnType.Id)]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
[IDXTable(IndexType.FullIndex)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }`